# Convert node-oracledb connection to strong-oracle connection in node

Tags: node.js, oracle

Let's say I have the following connection attributes in node-oracledb.

```
{
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
}
```

I noticed that strong-oracle connections don't accept a connectString.
Their format instead is

```
{ "hostname": "localhost", "user": "test", "password": "test", "database": "ORCL" };
```

How do I convert this to a strong-oracle format. I'm not sure database in the strong-oracle connection stands for.

Thanks

Comment: `{ "hostname": "localhost", "user": "hr", "password": "welcome", "database": "XE" };`

Comment: If there's a port, do I pass in port?